# In which stack exchange site should I ask about game development?

Tags: discussion, support, site-recommendation, development

I want to ask a question about the development of a popular game (not one that I am making, but a game by another company)  where should I ask it?

my question is:

> why didn't Minecraft's code moved to a c# based version after being purchased by Microsoft?

Is there is any suitable stack exchange site?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You won't likely find a site on Stack Exchange which would work well for this type of question. Only Microsoft knows why they made specific architectural decisions (unless there *coincidentally* happens to be an interview about it somewhere).

But more typically, questions about why [company] doesn't use [other platform] becomes quite tiring as folks who [love | hate] that platform come out of the woodwork to proclaim what everyone else should be using. It's just not a constructive dialogue to have, so we typically do not host that type of content in this Q&A.

Comment: it is not because I love/hate the platform, I just think it is the reasonable thing to do. but I get it, you don't deal with that stuff. I hoped you had a gaming community or something along those lines, but apparently not. thank you!

Comment: @AvivAviv If you are interested in a site for game developers, we have [Game Development](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com). It's an applied site to ask about the type of problems you might encounter when developing games, but discussions you were asking about would be off topic